# Running Apache CXF 2.7.10 deployment on WebSphere App Server 8.5

Tags: cxf, websphere-8

When I deployed our CXF web service on WebSphere 8.5 I received exception:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
... more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
... more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
... more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactory
```

root cause is using neethi implementation from WebSphere server libraries

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be set the PARENT_LAST ClassLoadeer order in:

```
Enterprise Applications > {app_name} > Class loader
```

and also for given Web Module at:

```
Enterprise Applications > {app_name} > Manage Modules > {web_module_name}
```

I'd like to set it in deployment configuration, but there is no way if the EAR app format is not used.